# EC2 Security Group and SSL for Node.js web application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS and recently I deployed a  node.js application on EC2. This is the security group that I have applied using the default VPC

[image]

When I try to access my node app using the public dns like this:

ec2-..-..-.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000 the app does not show up.

I logged into my ec2 instance using ssh and did `curl -v localhost:8000` and it served me the login page for the web app. So it means that the application is working fine.

When I change my security group configuration and add another rule

All TCP -> Anywhere. then the site opens up, although with an unsecure (http) connection.

My questions:

1. Is it safe to do All TCP > Anywhere ?
2. If I have already given the rules HTTP and HTTPS > anywhere then why won't it work?
3. How do I apply ssl certificate to my web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those security group rules are for the standard HTTP/HTTPS ports `80` and `443`. Your web server is currently running on port `8000`. You would need to add a rule to allow traffic over port `8000` if you want the URL `ec2-..-..-.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000` to work.

> Is it safe to do All TCP > Anywhere ?

Do you intend for this to be a public website that anyone can access? If so you pretty much have to open the security group to "Anywhere". You would need to harden your server configuration to make this "safe" though.

> How do I apply ssl certificate to my web server?

You could look into installing [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) on your server to provide a free SSL certificate. If you want to use a free SSL certificate from the AWS ACM service you will need to place an AWS load balancer in front of your server. A load balancer will also be able to forward ports `80` and `443` to your server's port `8000` which will solve your port number issue.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Yes I intend this to be a public website that anyone (or rather registered users, from anywhere) can access. I installed the Lets Encrypt but it seems I need a domain name to get started, same thing with AWS ACM, they ask a domain name. The issue is, I don't have any domain name for this app yet. Is there a way to provide ssl to the existing dns name (ec2-..-..-...compute.amazonaws.com:8000) ?

Comment: You won't be able to have a valid SSL certificate without first purchasing a domain name. Only the owner of the domain can obtain an SSL certificate for that domain, and you don't own the `compute.amazonaws.com` domain so you won't be able to obtain an SSL cerficiate for that domain.

Comment: Thanks for the info Mark. Can I apply the ACM to a subdomain? My client already has a website on her primary domain so we can probably create a subdomain and run the app on it?

Comment: Yes you can get the SSL certificate for a subdomain